# What is considered magical light for the purposes of the Darkness spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, vision-and-light

The [Darkness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/darkness) spell says (PHB 230):

> …nonmagical light can't illuminate it.

it also specifies:

> If any of this spell's area overlaps with an area of light created by a spell of 2nd level or lower, the spell that created the light is dispelled.

So my question is: what is considered magical light? is it only light from a spell or would light from a magical item (for example *flame tongue* sword) also be considered magical and, if so, what level would that light be considered?

Comment: *Flame tongue* is an interesting one... it's magical *fire* - but is it magical *light*? Or is it "natural" light created by the magical flames?

Comment: @Adeptus exactly. Currently its kinda ruining my drow campaign because a 80 ft magic light torch kinda nullifies drow darkness on any battlefield.

Comment: 20/20 hindsight I should have just asked this question directly about the flametongue sword

Comment: Probably means there's a second question worth posting!

Comment: Reminder: comments are for clarifying content, not posting small or incomplete answers. Please use answer posts to submit answers instead. Prior comments containing answers have been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All light sources from magical spells and effects can illuminate a Darkness spell and that includes light from items such as Flame Tongue (**RAW**).

Of course if light created by magical items can pierce if not dispel magical darkness we would need to calculate their level based on rarity, which to my knowledge is not present.

A good reference however is the **Spell scroll conversion** on page **200 of the DMG**. In it rare scrolls (which are technically considered magic items) harbour spells from 4th and 5th level. Considering Flame tongue is a rare sword, it would be up to your discretion to choose whether to assign it a level of 4 or 5.

That said [Jeremy Crawford's statement on twitter](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/722870799082721280) implies that only spells cast by characters illuminate magical darkness, which I think makes for more engaging encounters.

> **Matt Freeman:** @JeremyECrawford Does light from a magic weapon’s characteristics (not via a spell) count as magical that can illuminate a Darkness spell?
>
> **Jeremy Crawford:** Darkness cares only about light created by a spell. #DnD

Comment: It sounds to me like Crawford didn't fully read the question…

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'm not so sure about that, he could explicitly be saying that only light created by a spell counts as magical light

Comment: The 5e DMG states that spells cast by magic items are considered cast at their lowest level unless otherwise stated. It has nothing to do with rarity (though I know that's a popular home brew option).

Comment: @TylerH the DMG section on creating magic items links rarity to maximum spell level that can be cast from the weapon

Comment: I think Crawford's response is talking about the "dispelling" part of the spell description (only lower-level spells that create light are dispelled by *darkness*), which doesn't entirely address the general question. Magical sources of light are magical.

Comment: But the flame tounge sword isn't casting the light spell. It's just on fire.

Answer (score 9):

Non-magical light is light from a non-magical source: torches, lanterns, a bonfire, lava, the sun (assuming a physics basis for the sun in your world) etc. None of these penetrate the darkness.

Magical light is light from a magical source: spells, class powers that are magical in nature, magic items etc. The corollary of non-magical light *not* illuminating the darkness is that magical light does.

The fact that the darkness dispels *spells* of 2nd level or lower is a [furphy](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/furphy) - yes such spells are dispelled but higher level spells are not and *neither* are sources of non-magical light that are *not* spells.

A magic item that emits light as a non-spell effect is **not** a spell so it is not dispelled or affected in any way by the darkness. As a source of magical light it *will* illuminate the darkness. Of course, for magic items that allow you to *cast* a spell, that spell may be affected depending on its level - a spell is a spell whether innate to a class or from a magic item.

Comment: Do you perchance have a source for  this?

Comment: Oxford English Dictionary

Comment: Dictionary doesn't help. From the quotes in the question: Nonmagical light doesn't illuminate it; Spells of high enough level do illuminate it; Items *are not mentioned*. In previous editions, you could work out the level of an item's effect. I'm not sure if 5e has the same.

Comment: @Adeptus No. Nonmagical light doesn't illuminate it. Low level spells are ended by it. Ergo magical light that is not a low level spell illuminates it.

Comment: Here you go guys. Dale has this one precisely right. https://mobile.twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/722870799082721280

Comment: I don't want to clutter up the comments so further back and forth on this will  have to happen in a discussion chat, but the clarification I'm looking for @DaleM is about whether the light from the magic item needs to be direct (ring glows) or does even indirect light (sword creates fire magically, the fire creates light)  count as magical.

Comment: @ArtaSoral Unfortunately your original question didn't ask that. If you want to know if the light cast by the magical flames of a *flametongue* sword is itself magical light or mundane light, please ask a new question. Thanks!

Comment: this is untrue and confirmed by Sage advice a light source is not magical even if coming from a magical source unless indicated in the rule as a magic light (ex.: light spell).  for example the illumination made by a bonfire spell is NOT magical light.

Comment: @DaleM, thank you for bringing the word furphy into my world! But I fail to see how the fact that Darkness dispels spells of 2nd level or lower that create light overlapping its area is one -- that is exactly what Darkness does, and not a false report or rumor.

Comment: "Magical light is light from a magical source: spells, class powers that are magical in nature, magic items etc. "  Source needed for claim that light from magical items is, by definition, magical light. -1.

Answer (score 3):

Any spell, spell-like ability or magical item that creates explicitly magical light as (one of) its main effect(s), creates magical light inside its target area. If they also suffice the demand to be of high enough level, they can break through Darkness.

Dancing Lights (phb 220), Light (phb 255), Faerie Fire (phb 239), Sunlight (phb 279) are the most common examples, but also their item-bound variants work (a sunrod for example). However, you need still to cast them as a high enough level spell.

Comment: Part of the question is, how do you determine level of an item?

Comment: Hi @Trish, while looking up how to spell spell like ability, I just learned that [none such exist in 5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/83777/can-you-counterspell-a-spell-like-ability#:~:text=5e%20has%20no%20concept%20of,any%20of%20a%20Beholder's%20abilities.), thought it might be of interest

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin in 5E only by casting a spell that you can create a magical light everything else is considered non magical light.  The Sage confirmed a years ago.

Comment: @KilrathiSly thanks for sharing, that is good to know as it is not obvious.

Comment: @KilrathiSly I am not finding anything like that in SAC - as far as I know, we have only an unofficial tweet from JC about that.  Can you cite source?

Comment: Re: "You still need to cast them as a high enough level spell".  Note that SAC specifically disallows upcasting a lower level light-producing spell from dispelling darkness: "Can you cast darkness with a higher-level slot to end a spell of 3rd level or higher that creates light? No. The darkness spell can dispel only a light-creating spell of 2nd level or lower, no matter what spell slot is used for darkness. Similarly, the daylight spell can dispel only a darkness-creating spell of 3rd level or lower, regardless of the spell slot used."