# Magic effects of light and darkness

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, vision-and-light

I have a question about the magic effects inherent in light and darkness in d&d 5.

Within an area subject to [Darkness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/darkness) (spell level 2) if I wield a sword that magically emits light, the light is not affected by the spell. My question is what happens if have a magical effect of Darkness versus a magical effect of light or dim light?

Comment: Are you assuming that if you have a magical sword that emits light, then the light _must_ be magical?  Because that is rather [contentious](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/89888/23547), and AFAICT, not RAW.

Answer (score 7):

### *Darkness*, or the other effect will tell you what happens

*Darkness* says:

> nonmagical light can't illuminate it.
>
> [...]
>
> If any of this spell's area overlaps with an area of light created by a spell of 2nd level or lower, the spell that created the light is dispelled.

...so as you indicate, non-spell magical light is unaffected.

That said, *darkness* is not dispelled unless a specific effect says it would be. For example, the *daylight* spell sas:

> If any of this spell's area overlaps with an area of darkness created by a spell of 3rd level or lower, the spell that created the darkness is dispelled.

If this type of text is not present, the magical darkness is illuminated just like regular darkness by the magical light, but the darkness is still present, meaning that snuffing the magical light returns the magical darkness in spite of nonmagical lights.

Comment: Wow, almost at the same time!

Comment: Tangentially, it doesn't seem clear which wins if neither spell clarifies about it's interaction with the other, such as a magical light and a magical darkness that were the same level.

Answer (score 5):

#### The spell description provides information about the interaction of magical light and darkness.

There are a couple of lines that clarify how magical light and magical darkness from the [spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/darkness) interact.

The first one is (emphasis mine):

> A creature with darkvision can't see through this darkness, and **nonmagical light can't illuminate it**.

So, actually, the sword (being magical) can break the darkness spell.

The second bit is the following:

> If any of this spell's area overlaps with an area of light created by a spell of 2nd level or lower, the spell that created the light is dispelled.

Hence, a Cleric who casts the [*Light*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/light) cantrip while inside the Darkness' AoE cannot illuminate the area.

On the other hand, other spells can successfully counteract the Darkness spell: for example, [*Daylight*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/daylight):

> If any of this spell's area overlaps with an area of darkness created by a spell of 3rd level or lower, the spell that created the darkness is dispelled.