# Counterspell Reaction Question

Tags: dnd-5e

The trigger to use Counterspell is:

> 1 reaction, which you take when you see a creature within 60 feet of you casting a spell

But what if the enemy is not using a spell but a magic ability? Should I allow my players to spend the magic space trying to counter the "magic"?

Comment: Related on [Can you counterspell a spell-like ability?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/83777/can-you-counterspell-a-spell-like-ability)

Comment: Hello! i found my answer in this post [Answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115246/what-happens-if-you-cast-counterspell-on-a-creature-that-is-not-casting-a-spell)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Glad to hear you found an answer!