# Can a spell cast from a Spellwrought Tattoo be counterspelled?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, counterspelling

By D&D 5e rules, is a spell cast from a spellwrought tattoo subject to someone else casting *counterspell* against it?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more infos about posting Q&As here! You should develop more the body of your question: the tile is informative, but the body should contain more information.

Comment: Related: [Can you Counterspell a magic item?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/200054/63061) and [When casting a spell using a magic item, is the casting itself visible?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/145020/63061) I do not think that this is a dupe, since it is a specific case that needs a little bit of insights.

Answer (score 14):

#### Yes, since the casting using this tattoo is perceptible.

The section [Perceiving a caster at work](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/dungeon-masters-tools#PerceivingaCasteratWork) of Xanatar's Guide to Everything says (emphasis mine):

> But what about the act of casting a spell? Is it possible for someone to perceive that a spell is being cast in their presence? **To be perceptible, the casting of a spell must involve a verbal, somatic, or material component.** The form of a material component doesn’t matter for the purposes of perception, whether it’s an object specified in the spell’s description, a component pouch, or a spellcasting focus.

The complete description of the [Spellwrought Tattoo](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/2408275-spellwrought-tattoo) specifies (emphasis  mine):

> Once the tattoo is there, you can cast its spell, **requiring no material components. The tattoo glows faintly while you cast the spell and for the spell’s duration**. Once the spell ends, the tattoo vanishes from your skin.

We have hence two important piece of information:

- There is no need for material component, but it does not say anything about verbal or somatic ones.
- The tattoo glows *during the casting* and for the duration (for non instantaneous spells).

This meas that the casting is perceptible, mainly due to the glowing of the tattoo that acts as a somatic component: this lead to the possibility of counterspell it.

Anyway, the tattoo can be covered by clothes and similar<sup>1</sup>: the table for tattoo coverage provides some guidance.

| Tattoo Rarity | Area Covered |
| --- | --- |
| Common | One hand or foot or a quarter of a limb |
| Uncommon | Half a limb or the scalp |
| Rare | One limb |
| Very Rare | Two limbs or the chest or upper back |
| Legendary | Two limbs and the torso |

In this case, the player and the DM have to decide together how much tattoo is visible. Anyway, if the DM feels that making imperceptible the casting form this item is too powerful, they can decide that the glowing cannot be hidden by clothes.

It is true that this magic item works just once, hence in this case maybe is not so game-breaking allowing an imperceptible casting just for one time, but it depends on the table and on the DM.

---

<sup>1</sup> Credits to [Jack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/26732/jack) that pointed this out in the comments.

Comment: Nice job on showing how. +1

Comment: But does a spellwrought tattoo need to be visible?  If it were on the caster's back, and covered by several layers of clothing, or even armor, it doesn't seem like the faint glow would be visible.

Comment: @jack and there comes the DM ruling... But the rules for tattoo coverage may provide some help. I wil add that bit

Comment: @Jack Done: have a look if it addresses what you pointed out.

Comment: I think it's fine, and already +1'd.  But . . . the spellwrought tattoos are so annoying -- a great concept, but I feel like they took it out of the oven before the toothpick was clean.  As you point out, they don't mention whether the spell still requires verbal and somatic, so RAW one would have to assume they're still required.  So . . . glowing aside, the only thing making a spellwrought tattoo casting more stealthy than a regular casting, is lack of material component, which doesn't really make it much more stealthy.

Comment: @Jack yes, I agree: V and S seems to be still needed, indeed beside the glowing this makes the casting not stealthy/imperceivable to me.

Comment: Ty for your answer, my doubt comes from the DMG rule in the page 141 Spells sections that says "Some magic items allow the user to cast a spell from the item, often by expending charges from it. The spell is cast at the lowest possible spell and caster level, doesn't expend any of the user's spell slots, and requires no components unless the item's description says otherwise."

That's why I tought that RAW it isn't posible to counterspell

Comment: @Pablo Yep, I can see from the confusion may come: indeed, the focus here is on the part "unless the item's description says otherwise.".

Comment: @Eddymage Ok, but the "The tattoo glows faintly while you cast the spell and for the spell’s duration" it's not a component of the spell but a component of the magic item, but I guess we can consider it an ad hoc component as Jeremy said here: https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/988882563501510656?s=20

Again, ty for your help. :)

Comment: @Pablo JC's tweets are not official anymore, and remember that he proved several times to contradict the rules and also himself...